# Software for Photoevent/fair

Tags: photography

I need a configurable Software for a photoevent. We have a photowall and the user/guest should just click start, after 10 seconds the picture is taken. Then he is asked by the software: print? send as email? publish on Event-Wall? And the software should add a Logo to the picture. So the Software should be end-user optimized.

Sadly I cant find the described Software with my google search. I saw this setups on different fairs and now my boss want one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to search for is "photo booth". One I have come across in the past is [FreeBooth](https://sourceforge.net/projects/freebooth/). To quote:

> This is a simple photo booth application. You can take pictures with a
>   camera (e.g. a dslr) and they will be shown in the application
>   immediately. You need no internet at your event location. Every user
>   can save an Email-adress to his favourite picture and you can send all
>   Emails via the sending wizard when you have internet again e.g. the
>   next day. But it also supportes direct email sending if you have
>   internet. To get the pictures into the booth software you have to use
>   a tethering software like EOS Utility for Windows or gphoto2 or
>   darktable for Linux

There are a couple of similar older applications on sourceforge, if you do a search there.